# Why does this Program run from Aptana IDE and not in python command?

Tags: python, typeerror

The following code results in a

```
htmlbody,emailaddress = ConnEmailParser()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

Error but works fine in IDE. Emails are being sent and PDF files generated. But from command line just `ConnEmailParser()` is working.

What can I do, that the program runs smoothly?

Here the code snipped:

```
import imaplib
import email
import quopri
from cStringIO import StringIO
import ho.pisa as pisa
from datetime import datetime
import logging
import smtplib
from email.generator import Generator
from email.MIMEMultipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.MIMEBase import MIMEBase
from email.MIMEText import MIMEText
from email.Utils import formatdate
from email import Encoders

def sendPdfSurvey():

  def ConnEmailParser():
    try:
        saver = StringIO()
        SERVER = "server"
        USER  = "user"
        PASSWORD = "nono"
        subject="a certain phrase"
        imap4 = imaplib.IMAP4(SERVER)
        imap4.login(USER, PASSWORD)
        imap4.select()
        imap4.search(None, 'ALL') 
        typ, data = imap4.search(None,'(UNSEEN SUBJECT "%s")' % subject) #looking for phrase
        count = 0
        for num in data[0].split():
            count = count + 1 # this is stupid but it gets just oone messsage
            if count ==1 :
                typ, data = imap4.fetch(num,'(RFC822)')
                email7 = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
                varSubject = email7['subject']
                # The phase from above has an emailaddress in the subject field
                emailaddressraw = varSubject[13:] 
                emailaddressmedium = emailaddressraw.replace("<","")
                emailaddress= emailaddressmedium.replace(">","")  
                msg = email.message_from_string(data[0][1])
                typ, data = imap4.store(num,'+FLAGS','\Seen')
                a=str(msg)
                i= a.decode('quopri').decode('utf-8')
                saver.write(i)
                savercontent = saver.getvalue()
                # body of the email is html and all of the header elements get deleted
                planhtml = savercontent.split('<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">')[1].strip()
                return planhtml, emailaddress.strip()     
        saver.close()
        imap4.close()
        imap4.logout()
    except:
        "could not get participant email!"

#here somewhere is the trouble maker  

htmlbody,emailaddress = ConnEmailParser()
filenamePDF= "UmfrageEthics_%s.pdf" % datetime.utcnow().strftime('%m%d%H%M%S%f')

def printPdf():
    try:
        html = htmlbody
        result = StringIO()
        pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(StringIO(html.encode("UTF-8")), result, encoding='UTF-8')
        filetoparse=open(filenamePDF,"wb")
        filetoparse.write(result.getvalue())
        filetoparse.close()
        #pisa.startViewer(filenamePDF)
    except:
        print "could not write PDF"  


def sendPdfParticipant():
    try:
        oNachricht = MIMEMultipart()
        oNachricht['From'] = 'some@email.com'
        oNachricht['To'] =  emailaddress
        oNachricht['Date'] = formatdate(localtime= True)
        oNachricht['Subject'] = 'A subject'
        oAnhang = MIMEBase('application','octet-stream')
        oAnhang.set_payload(open(filenamePDF,'rb').read())
        Encoders.encode_base64(oAnhang)
        oAnhang.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment;filename = some.pdf') 
        message_text_plain = u'Some message...'
        oNachricht.attach(MIMEText(message_text_plain.encode('utf-8'), 'plain', 'UTF-8'))
        io = StringIO()
        g = Generator(io, False)
        g.flatten(oNachricht)


        oNachricht.attach(oAnhang)


        user = 'user'
        pwd = 'pwd'
        smtpserver = smtplib.SMTP("smtp.raumopol.de",587)
        smtpserver.ehlo()
        smtpserver.starttls()
        smtpserver.ehlo
        smtpserver.login(user, pwd)
        smtpserver.sendmail('som@eemail.com',emailaddress,oNachricht.as_string())
        smtpserver.quit()
    except:
        print"could no send data"

sendPdfSurvey()
```

Comment: Fundamental SO posting rule: If you have an exception, include the stack trace and indicate which line caused the exception.

Comment: @Jim Garrison: Citation needed.

Comment: Common Sense: You don't go to the doctor and say "It hurts, but I'm not going to tell you where".

Comment: I thought that ....htmlbody,emailaddress = ConnEmailParser()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable... was the highest bit of information i could get...i will try traceback and will give you hopefully better information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `def ConnEmailParser()`, check if `data` is `None` before calling `data[0].split()`.
If it is `None`, check if `imap4` is correctly initiated and if login worked. If that is the case, post a reduced part of your code pinpointing on where it actually goes wrong.

As @Jim Garrison pointed out, a traceback would help us (and you) a lot. This is how:

```
import traceback

try:
    some_code...
except TypeError:
    traceback.print_exc()
```

---

**edit** (based on your comment)

When you encode a unicode string, you are replacing characters that are not part of ASCII with codes as '\xfc'. Apparently, saver.write() tries to encode your already encoded text, after first interpreting it as unicode (you got `u'\xfc'`). So don't encode yourself. If it still goes wrong, see how you can change the encoding (e.g. 'utf-8', 'cp1252'). Get the current encoding of your OS with

```
import locale
encoding=locale.getlocale()[1]
```

Comment: okay it says: saver.write(i) UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codex can't encode character u'\xfc' in position 175 0: ordinal not in range(128)....? I did the encoding a couple of line before...or was that wrong?